# Dynamic Programming Relation for Bob and assignment Problem

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am struggling to form recurring relations for the below problem.

Bob's current semester is coming to an end and he is given N assignments numbered from 1 to N to complete to pass the semester. These assignments are from B subjects numbered from 1 to B.
Bob will do these assignment in numerical order over multiple days. Bob will do at least one assignment each day till he has no assignments left to do.
Also, Bob can do more than one assignment on the same day but he doesn't want to do more than one assignments from same subject on the same day.
Bob wants to know in how many ways he can complete these assignments under these conditions.
Two ways are different if the number and type of assignment done on any day are not equal.

Given an integer array A, where 1 <= A[i] <= B referring i'th assignment belongs to A[i] subject and an integer B return the total number of ways modulo 1000000007.

Problem Constraints
1 ≤ N, B ≤ 100000
1 ≤ A[i] ≤ M

Input Format
The first input is an integer array A.
The second input in an integer B.

Output Format
Return an integer modulo 1000000007.

Example Input
Input - 1:
A = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2]
B = 2

Input - 2:

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = 6

Example Output
Output - 1:
5

Output - 2:

32

I will appreciate any hint or solution for this one. I have spent around 6hrs on this but still not able to solve

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
dp[i] denotes the number of possible ways to partition the array such that the last partition is closed at i.

```
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(long i=a;i<b;i++)
int mod=int(1e9+7);
void add_self(ll &A,const ll &B){
    A=(A+B)%mod;
}
vector<ll> dp;

int solve(vector<int> &A, int B) {
        vector<int> frq(B+10,0);
    int n=A.size();
    vector<pair<int,int>> arr;
    FOR(i,0,A.size()){
      arr.pb({frq[A[i]],A[i]}); frq[A[i]]++;
    }
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
    dp=vector<ll>(n+1,0); dp[0]=1;
    vector<int> pos(n+1,0),pos2(B+1,0);
    FOR(i,0,arr.size()){
        pos[i+1]=pos2[arr[i].si];
        pos2[arr[i].si]=i+1;
    }
    vector<ll> pre(n+1,0); pre[0]=1;
    FOR(i,1,n+1){
        ll val=pre[i-1]; if(pos[i]){val=(val-pre[pos[i]-1]+mod)%mod;}
        add_self(dp[i],val);
        add_self(pre[i],dp[i]+pre[i-1]);
    }
    return dp[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Brute Force Approach
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
void solve(int n,int a[],int b,set<int>& s,int start,int end,int &count)
{
    if(end==n || start==n){
        count++;
        return;
    }
    //for(int tem:s)cout<<"S1"<<count<<" "<<tem<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    if(s.find(a[end])==s.end())
    {
        s.insert(a[end]);
        solve(n,a,b,s,start,end+1,count);
    }
    s.clear();
    s.insert(a[end]);
    solve(n,a,b,s,end,end+1,count);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>a[i];
    int b;
    cin>>b;
    int count=0;
    set<int> s;
    s.insert(a[0]);
    solve(n,a,b,s,0,1,count);
    cout<<"ans "<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).